# Sequelize.js: How to do find with JSONB object that includes array field

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I have a model like this:

```
class Project extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init({
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            user: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },
            data: {
                type: DataTypes.JSONB,
            }
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: "projects",
        });
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to find `project` by the `name` and `data` fields like this:

```
myProject = 
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "data": {
        "status": "draft",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "tag1",
                "createdBy": "user1"
            },
            {
                "name": "tag2",
                "id": "user2"
            }
        ]
    }
}

await Project.findOne({ where: myProject});
```

Then I got this error: `Error: Invalid value { name: 'tag1', createdBy: 'user1' }`. Looks like the `findOne` method does not recognize the array in my JSONB object.

Is it even possible to find with JSONB object that has `array` field? Could anyone point me to the correct direction? Thanks!

Comment: It crashes even before the 'data' segment. The error you've got is caused because your model doesnt have a column called `name` and in your query, you're querying for it.

Comment: That’s a good catch but the problem is not that. It was a typo when I submitted the post.